# How to read a string that is enclosed in specific tags and replace it with a different string?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have a string that has multiple places to parse for strings enclosed in <%%> tags and replace it with appropriate values. If it is only one occurence of the tags, I could use IndexOf method to read the string and then use Replace method. How can I do it with multiple occurences of the tags? Thanks for any suggestions.

Example:

> > Read text1 <%GetName%> Read text2 <%GetID%> Read tex3 <%GetNumber%> and more

The output should be

> > Read text1 Value1 Read text2 Value2 Read text3 Value3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could consider using regular expressions - specifically the [Regex.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx) method

The regex you would require would be something like:

```
<%([^%]+)%>
```

Using a MatchEvaluator, you can replace the whole string with something specific based on the match:

```
var newText = Regex.Replace(textToCheck, "<%([^%]+)%>", (m) => {
    switch (m.Groups[1].Value)
    {
        case "GetName":
            return "New value";
        ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex and a dictionary to map the values.....

```
var toReplace = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"GetName", "Value1" },
    {"GetID", "Value2" },
    {"GetNumber", "Value3" },
};

string input = @"Read text1 <%GetName%> Read text2 <%GetID%> Read tex3 <%GetNumber%> and more";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"<%(.+?)%>", m => toReplace[m.Groups[1].Value]);
```

OUTPUT:

```
Read text1 Value1 Read text2 Value2 Read tex3 Value3 and more
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an alternative to *regular expressions* using a dictionary to map template parameters to values to replace them in a given string template:

```
public static class StringTemplatingExtensions
{
    public static string ParseTemplate(this string template, IDictionary<string, object> valueMap)
    {
        foreach(var pair in valueMap)
        {
            template = template.Replace($"<%{pair.Key}%>", pair.Value.ToString());
        }

        return template;
    }
}
```

So it can be used as follows:

```
var template = "Read text1 <%GetName%> Read text2 <%GetID%> Read tex3 <%GetNumber%>";
var parsed = template.ParseTemplate(new Dictionary<string, object> {
    { "GetName", "Matías" },
    { "GetID", "114894" },
    { "GetNumber", "282893" }
});
```

Note that this solution is less flexible than others, because it won't support `<% VARIABLE %>`, `<%VARIABLE %>`, but just `<%VARIABLE%>` (without spaces). BTW, it's a very simple but yet effective way of implementing your requirement and it just works!